# Microsoft Anti XSS Library encoding ampersands?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, antixsslibrary

I am currently using the **Microsoft AntiXSS library** and using the `GetSafeHtmlFragment` method as follows:

```
public static string SanitizeHtml(this string s)
{
    return Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(s);
}
```

However, if I pass in a string like this:

> `black & white`

... it is encoding the ampersand so it becomes:

> `black &amp; white`

Is this normal behaviour for this library? Is there a way of preventing it from encoding this character?

Comment: I believe that's normal behavior since you're using `GetSafeHtmlFragmet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this normal behaviour for this library?

Yes, it fixes your HTML since you are using `GetSafeHtmlFragment`. Otherwise you would have ended up with invalid HTML fragment. In HTML the `&` character has special meaning. I don't think this behavior could be modified.

Comment: I see - so what would be the normal practice when outputting user generated content (safely), but whilst displaying the '&' characters (rather than their encoded equivalents)? Should I be using a different library/method?

Comment: @marcusstarnes, if you want to display this in a web page (HTML) you should encode it. If you want to display the `&` character in a web page you should use `&amp;` and that's exactly what the AntiXss library does.

Comment: OK I understand, but my problem is that the actual characters &amp; are being rendered to screen. I am using Razor, so am I right in thinking the only way around this is to wrap any outputs with Html.Raw("black &amp; white")? I just want &'s to be displayed as &'s and not &amp; but to still use the AntiXss library so as to ensure any malicious script etc is stripped prior to rendering? Should I just essentially call @Html.Raw(GetSafeHtmlFragment("black & white")) ?

Comment: @marcusstarnes, that's exactly what you need: `@Html.Raw` if you want to avoid HTML encoding. If you had stated that you were using Razor in your original question that would have been clear earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best solution. If you use HTML.Raw() then you are leaving yourself vulnerable to XSS attacks unless you can be absolutely sure that the string is safe all the time and for all uses of HTML.Raw().